# Why "reverse-i-search" does not work on my centos sytem?

Tags: bash, command-history

When i press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>,  the "reaverse-i-search" works well:

[image]

but then when i press "arrow up" key, none history commands show, just nothing happens!

Any configuration not compare?

Comment: Check for inputrc file in your bash what are the keys are referred in the history search

Comment: "\e[5~": beginning-of-history
"\e[6~": end-of-history                                                                    no idea of what's the meaning? what should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the reverse search, you need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> again to do the backwards search.

Comment: thank you, seems someone making it easier in my previous machine.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you have your <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> keys bound to `beginning-of-history` and `end-of-history` which, respectively, means:

- Move to the first line in the history
- Move to the end of the input history, i.e., the line currently being entered.

If, as your question seems to indicate, the functionality that you are looking for is to move up and down through your history incrementally, you would change these bindings in your `.inputrc` to `history-search-{backward,forward}`, like so:

```
"\e[5~": history-search-backward
"\e[6~": history-search-forward
```

You can see a list of all of the [readline bindings here](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_readline.htm).